# Simplified Trips on Project (STOPS) by FTA

Tags: python

Anyone happen to know what language it's coded in? IIRC, it was the brainchild of someone at a consulting firm called RSG. It uses some Python scripts, but that doesn't seem to be what it's programmed in. You can download the software from FTA [here](https://www.transit.dot.gov/funding/grant-programs/capital-investments/stops-documentation-and-software)